# Font Awesome icon moves across input field with window resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize

New to css. Making a page responsive to resizing. I have a form input field, which is centred and remains in that position as the page is resized. However, the fa-icon does not hold its position and moves across the input field. I've tried setting the left parameter as a % and played around with the media query settings but can't get it to stick.

html:

```
<body>

 <div id="wrap">
 <div id="main">

<form action="index.php" method="post" id="srchForm" autocomplete="off"><pre>

<div class="inputWithIcon">
  <input name="msg" id="search" type="text" autofocus value= ""></input> 
 <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
<div id="error"></div> 
</div>

</pre></form>

</div>
</div>

</body>
```

css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

#wrap { 
   width: 960px;
   min-height: 100%;
   margin-left: auto;
   position: relative;
   margin-right: auto;
}

#main{
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#srchForm {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -30px;
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
}

input:focus, select:focus {
    outline:none !important;
}

input[type=text] {
  position: center;
  width: 480px;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #E8E8E8;
  color: #484848;
}

.inputWithIcon input[type=text]{
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.inputWithIcon {
  position: relative;
  color: #E8E8E8;
}

i.fa.fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 19px;
  left: 35%;
  top:36%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 959px){
  #wrap{
    width:100%;
  }

}
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hzqLburo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/k6pcrL79/3/

```
<form action="#">

  <div class="input">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
     <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

```
.input{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.input input{
  width:200px;
}

.input i{
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

In your example fa-icon hold position. It looks like not but it holds. Your problem is your fixed size of input. You should use % or vw units instead of px. For responsive it is neccessary. 
However you should use flexbox for this what you want instead of position absolute. Hold on i post you some code

Comment: Thank you. That looks good. I wanted the icon in side the search input field as well. To what extent can you use flexbox? Can you use it for a whole page, or is it really for these specific situations?

Comment: I recomend you this page https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ . I use it very often. Flexbox is awesome attribute and it is used to responsive layouts. Almost any layout you can do with this.

Comment: Thank you looks like a helpful link. Sorry I wasnt very clear before. I'd like the icon to be inside the input box, like the Google search input box.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wx4f1Lc5/6/ If this is what you want please make answer as correct :)

Comment: With flexbox you don't need to change the input width to vw units?